# Action<T> Delegate Exception warning

Tags: c#, lambda, exception, delegates

I need to understand the exception handling model behind an Action delegate... I have the following code:

```
Action<DataRow> ProcessDatafeedRow = datafeedRow => {

    try {
        //  do many things...
    }
    catch (Exception exc) {
        //  log the exception, return without error
    }

};

foreach (DatafeedRow row in datafeedDataTable) {        
    ProcessDatafeedRow(row);        
}
```

ReSharper gives me a warning:  `Possible 'System.Exception' from delegate invocation`.

What exceptions can be thrown from the invocation of a delegate defined by Action, Func, etc.?  What would cause them, when would they occur, etc... I would have thought my inner try..catch would have ensured the caller could invoke the Action without worrying about exceptions.

Comment: I tried your code and Resharper does not give me the warning. Is this the exact code that you have?

Comment: SystemException?? Did you get the Java version?  Any exception can be thrown when you invoke a delegate, except SystemException.  Look through the Resharper config and turn it off.

Comment: Minus the code represented by the comments, yes.  The error message is actually coming from the Exceptional plugin, which I believe relies on code issues exposed by ReSharper.  If you run ReSharper -> Inspection -> Code Issues in Current Project, do you get a Common Practices and Code Improvements warning?

Comment: @HansPassant, I missed a period - System.Exception, sorry

Comment: @JamesKing, I tried that and I don't get that warning. Try to reproduce the issue in a new project

Comment: @YacoubMassad, if I create a new console project with nothing but an action with a try..catch that does nothing but return, I still get that warning.  It must be coming from the Exceptional plugin, but I'm pretty sure that plugin relies on information exposed by ReSharper.

Comment: I don't have this warning even with Exceptional plugin. Anyway most likely it just means delegate invocation may throw some exception - it won't analyze the body of that delegate, so does not know if it really can or not.

Comment: Strange.  So you think it has nothing to do with an implicit .Invoke() call?